# Why is $|x|^2$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why should $|x|^2$ be differentiable?

$$f(x)=|x|^2$$

Right limit:
Since $h>0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{(|h|)^2}{h}=\frac{h^2}{h}=h$$
Here h value will be positive.

Left limit:
Since $h<0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{(|h|)^2}{h}=\frac{-h^2}{h}=-h$$
Here h value will be negative.

Right limit will not be equal to the left limit. Why is it that $|x|^2$ is differentiable?

Comment: $|h|^2$ is positive if $h$ is nonzero, regardless of whether $h$ is negative or positive.

Comment: Your function is simply $\;|x|^2=|x^2|=x^2\;$ , the canonical parabola ...

Comment: The $-h$ should never have been there in the first place; $(-h)^2 = h^2$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein That $-$ sign came because I was dividing a positive $(|h|)^2$ by a negative value. Or am I wrong? btw I got the answer to the actual question, that I dropped the limit too early.

Comment: @SiddharthVenu You have $|h| = -h$, so $\frac{(|h|)^2}{h} = \frac{(-h)^2}{h} = \frac{(-1)^2 h^2}{h} = \frac{h^2}{h} = h$.

Comment: So Alex's answer that you accepted doesn't actually address the main issue with what you have written, IMO.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I totally understood your point now, brother. Thanks to people like you, learning calculus is easy :D Can you please post this as an answer so that I could accept it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SiddharthVenu Done.

Comment: Your second derivative has ${\rm d}x$ moving towards the negative _x_ axis. You need to reverse the subtraction order on the numerator when $h<0$.

Comment: The expression $\lim_{h\to 0^-} f(h)/h = h$ is meaningless. The $h$ on the left side is a dummy variable; what is it on the right?

Comment: An example where the issue you have highlighted  does actually arise is $x|x|$, but it's still differentiable as explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've calculated the left hand limit incorrectly:

For $h<0$, you have $|h|=-h$, so $\frac{(|h|)^2}{h}=\frac{(−h)^2}{h}=\frac{(−1)^22h^2}{h}=\frac{h^2}{h}=h$. So there's no disparity between the two sides at all.

That said, to reiterate what others have focused on: You do need to make sure you finish computing your limits. Even if it were true that $\frac{f(h)}{h} = h$ for $h>0$ and $\frac{f(h)}{h} = -h$ for $h<0$, it would still follow that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} h = 0,$$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^-} -h = 0,$$ so they match, therefore $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0}=\frac{x^2-0}x=\lim_{x \to0}x=0$$

Observe that $\;|x|^2=|x^2|=x^2$

Comment: Yes I got the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the limit calculations (you dropped the limit to early). Should be:

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(|h|)^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{h^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}h=0.$$

Comment: Of course I did that, haha. I will correct my mistake next time

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that $|x|^2 = x^2$ let us split the function and try the two limits

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} (-x)^2 & x<0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ (x)^2 & x>0 \end{cases} $$

$$f'_{+} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(h)^2-0}{h} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0} h$$

$$f'_{-} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(-h)^2-0}{h} = \lim_{x=0,h\rightarrow 0} h$$

both are the same.

The problem with your calculation is that you have $|h|$ in the denominator forcing it to be always positive, instead of letting it naturally come out the way it is supposed to.